# C, GTK: display stream of RGB images at < 60 fps

Tags: c, stream, gtk, rgb

I'm developing an application that shall receive images from a camera device and display them in a GTK window.

The camera delivers raw RGB images (3 bytes per pixel, no alpha channel, fixed size) at a varying frame rate (1-50 fps).

I've already done all that hardware stuff and now have a callback function that gets called with every new image captured by the camera.

**What is the easyest but fast enough way to display those images in my window?**

Here's what I already tried:

- using **`gdk_draw_rgb_image()`** on a gtk drawing area: basically worked, but rendered so slow that the drawing processes overlapped and the application crashed after the first few frames, even at 1 fps capture rate.
- allocating a **GdkPixbuf** for each new frame and calling **`gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf()`** on a gtk image widget: only displays the first frame, then I see no change in the window. May be a bug in my code, but don't know if that will be fast enough.
- using **Cairo** (`cairo_set_source_surface()`, then `cairo_paint()`): seemed pretty fast, but the image looked striped, don't know if the image format is compatible.

Currently I'm thinking about trying something like gstreamer and treating those images like a video stream, but I'm not sure whether this is like an overkill for my simple mechanism.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Cairo defines its CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24 image surface pixels in terms of 32 bit words, so in memory on an little endian machine, the pixels will be BGR0BGR0, you are probably using the reverse, or are not putting in the 0 byte, hence the stripping.

Comment: @lynix I need to code the same thing. Can you share how to cairo to get webcam feed?

Comment: @inckka: It's been 4 years since then, and your question is too general for anyone to give you a precise answer. My specific problem has been solved [this way](http://pastebin.com/QMCgaaUT).

Comment: @lynix Where do you call the img_update function?
Inside the main with a expose-event callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire GdkRGB API seems to be deprecated, so that's probably not the recommended way to solve this.

The same goes for the call to [render a pixbuf](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Drawing-Primitives.html#gdk-draw-pixbuf). The documentation there points at Cairo, so the solution seems to be to continue investigating why your image looked incorrect when rendered by Cairo.

Comment: Thanks, this explains why I couldn' find any complete tutorial for GdkRGB-stuff.
I'll go with cairo now, just wondering if it is fast enough for the 50 fps

Answer (score 1):

unwind is right, cairo is the way to go if you want something that will work in GTK2 and GTK3. As your samples are RGB without alpha, you should use the [CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html#cairo-format-t) format. Make sure the surface you paint is in that format. Also try to make sure that you're not constantly allocating/destroying the surface buffer if the input image keeps the same size.

Comment: Thanks, I've started implementing with cairo.

Comment: As I'm new to stackoverflow, shall I ask questions about how to solve one problem I encounter whith cairo here or in a new thread? :)

Comment: @lynix If you have a new question, post a new question. Stack Overflow is based on *questions*, not "threads". It's not a discussion forum.