# C, cairo: render stream of RGB images

Tags: c, image, gtk, rgb, cairo

I'd like to display a **stream of raw RGB images** (fixed size, without alpha channel, < 60fps) in a GTK window. I [was told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849105/c-gtk-display-stream-of-rgb-images-at-60-fps) to use cairo here.

My code works fine with single images and still for a stream of images at about 1 FPS.
Above 2 FPS my application crashes with Xorg errors, so I think my cairo mechanic is wrong.

It looks kind of like this:

```
unsigned char    *image_data;
cairo_surface_t  *image;
GtkWidget        *main_window;

void init_window()
{
    // (...) all the GTK initialization stuff

    image_data = malloc(IMAGE_BYTES);
    image = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(image_data,
                CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24,
                IMAGE_W, IMAGE_H,
                cairo_format_stride_for_width(CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24, IMAGE_W));
}

void update_image()
{
    cairo_t *cr;

    cr = gdk_cairo_create(main_window->window);
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, image, 10, 10);
    cairo_paint(cr);

    cairo_destroy(cr);
}

int main()
{
    // (...)
    init_window();

    while ((image_data = receive_image()) != NULL)
        update_image();
}
```

**What is the right way to render series of images in cairo?**
Which structures should be reused, which ones have to be recreated?

Comment: Hint: This has been done for UVC cams: https://github.com/ufo-kit/libuca , just in case you are dealing with cameras.

Answer (score 1):

This may be unrelated, but the way you update the image in the main is incorrect. Where's your call to `gtk_main` ? Moreover, and in response to a new image available from the camera, generate an expose-event to update your window.

BTW, it looks like you're drawing directly to the main window, which is not IMHO the best thing to do. Add inside your main window a GtkDrawingArea, and draw in that one in response to the `expose-event` signal (if you're using GTK2), or the `draw` signal (if using GTK3).

You could also handle your incoming images like an event source using [GSource](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSource).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I finally found some example code on the cairo homepage and changed it to fit my needs (http://cairographics.org/animationrotation).